# parametrize to csv file url in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I configured this in following steps: in this moment I prepare following csv file:

```
protocol    $url
${dev}      http://10.200.XXX.XX/{$url}
${trial}    trial.mycompany.io{$url}
${product}  product.mycompany.io{$url}
```

then I add to my Test Plan -> `Config element` - `CSV Data Set Config`, and then I add `Switch Controller`, 
and I have `WebSocket Samplers` by Peter Doornbosch and I dont have `HTTP Samplers` and `WebSocket Samplers`;

In `Switch Controller` I add `HTTP Request` and `WebSocket request-response Sampler`. In HTTP request I set

`protocol:http`,

`server name or IP: localhost`,

port number 8080.

HTTP request method POST,

path: ${URL}, and

parameters Add: `Name: Value ${protocol} ws://{$URL} ${protocol} http://{$URL}`

and in `WebSocket request-response Sampler` I set: `use existing connection`

do I correctly set the parameterization of the url variable, do I do something wrong, how to correct it, what to change?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of [parameterization in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide) seems to be vague, as far as I get your idea your CSV file should look like:

```
protocol, url
http, some-http-host/some-http-path
ws, some-websocket-host/some-websocket-path
http, some-http-host/some-other-http-path
etc.
```

Then you should be able to use it in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) as

[image: JMeter CSV Data Set Cofnig]

Switch Controller will allow you to choose either HTTP Request or WebSocket samplers depending on `${protocol}` variable value so when `${protocol}` is equal to `http` - only children of the `http` [Simple Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller) will be executed and `ws` will not be run and vice versa, when `${protocol}` is `ws` - only `ws` samplers are being kicked off and `http` are not executed.

[image: JMeter Switch Controller]

And in Samplers you can refer the values from the CSV file as `${protocol}` and `${url}` correspondingly

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Open cmd prompt, change the path to the jmeter bin folder.
Now write jmeter command to run:

```
jmeter -n -t testing.jmx
```

If you want to log the results then use -l with a file name for output, So the command will be changed to

```
jmeter -n -t testing.jmx -l results.jtl
```